# Mongoose.js store unknown object in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose, populate

I am creating sort of a conversation app, I want a user to be able to continue their conversation from anywhere via email and SMS. Right now I have a conversation schema like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var validator = require('validator');

var ConversationSchema = new Schema({
    contact: [
        { 
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Contact'
        }
    ],
    conversation: {

    }
});

var Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation', ConversationSchema);
```

In the conversation object, I want an `Email` or an `SMS` object to be able to be store. It will not be known how many Email's or how many `SMS`'s will be in the conversation object, nor what order they arrive in. When I query for the conversation, to display it, I want to populate all of the `Email` and `SMS` objects.

How can I ensure `conversation` can hold different types of objects, and that each of those objects can be populated when the conversation is requested?

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I can imagine that populating every object would be extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you'd better use an array for conversation, such as:

```
conversation: {
    sms: [],
    email: []
}
```

or,, if you put `[Schema.Types.Mixed]` for the type, you will be able to save any kind of object inside.